# Combine Multiple SQL Server Query Results

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, subquery

Below are two search queries that work separately. Both queries search the same table (`KnowledgeBaseArticles`) and take in a search string with the parameters `@SearchWithWildcard` and `@SearchParam`.

I want to combine these queries into a stored procedure (maybe two) that would return one combined result set without any duplicates. I've tried to create a temporary table of the first query and nest the results in the second and I applied the first query to stored procedure and attempted to execute and join the results in the second but the syntax is wrong and doesn't work.

If anyone can suggest the best approach to start to build this into one query I would greatly appreciate the assistance.

First search query:

```
declare @i1 int;
declare @i2 int;
declare @Word varchar(100);
declare @Words table (Word varchar(100) not null);
declare @WordCount as integer;
declare @SearchWithWildcard nvarchar(1000)
declare @MatchType int = 0

set nocount on

-- Parse the @SearchWithWildcard to extract all words:
if (@MatchType != 2)
begin
  set @SearchWithWildcard = ' ' + @SearchWithWildcard + ' ';
  set @i1 = 1;

  while (@i1 != 0)
  begin
    set @i2=charindex(' ', @SearchWithWildcard, @i1+1)

    if (@i2 != 0)
    begin
      set @Word = rtrim(ltrim(substring(@SearchWithWildcard, @i1+1, @i2-@i1)))
      if @Word != '' insert into @Words select @Word
      end
    set @i1 = @i2
    end
  end
else
  insert into @Words select ltrim(rtrim(@SearchWithWildcard))
-- Get the total # of words:

set @WordCount = (select count(*) from @Words)

-- Return Results in order of relevance:
select a.MatchPct, T.*
from KnowledgeBaseArticles T
inner join  (select ID, Count(*)  * 1.0 / @WordCount as MatchPct from KnowledgeBaseArticles T
inner join @Words W on ' ' + T.KeyWords + ' ' like '%[^a-z]' + Word + '[^a-z]%'
group by ID) a on T.ID = a.ID
where MatchPct = 1 or @MatchType <>1 
order by MatchPct
```

Second search query:

```
Declare @SearchWithWildcard NVARCHAR(1000)
Declare @SearchParam nvarchar(1000)
Declare @CatID integer
set @CatID = 0

BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF @SearchParam != ''
    SET @SearchWithWildcard = @SearchParam
ELSE
    SET @SearchWithWildcard = ''

IF @CatID = 0 AND NULLIF(@SearchParam, '') IS NULL
   SELECT * 
   FROM KnowledgeBaseArticles 
   WHERE Deleted = 0

ELSE IF @CatID = 0 AND NULLIF(@SearchParam, '') IS NOT NULL
   SELECT * 
   FROM KnowledgeBaseArticles
   WHERE (ArticleTextOnly like '% ' + @SearchWithWildcard + ' %' OR Title like '% ' + @SearchWithWildcard + ' %') and Deleted = 0

ELSE IF @CatID > 0 AND NULLIF(@SearchParam, '') IS NOT NULL
   SELECT * 
   FROM KnowledgeBaseArticles
   WHERE CategoryID = @CatID AND (ArticleTextOnly like '% ' + @SearchWithWildcard + ' %' OR Title like '% ' + @SearchWithWildcard + ' %') and Deleted = 0

ELSE IF @CatID > 0 AND NULLIF(@SearchParam, '') IS NULL
   SELECT * 
   FROM KnowledgeBaseArticles
   WHERE CategoryID = @CatID and Deleted = 0
END
```

Comment: "syntax is wrong and doesn't work" what syntax did you use and in what way didn't it work? (i.e. post the error message). What you could do is add to your second query a `NOT EXISTS` condition that only inserts results that aren't already in the table. Having said that, maybe if you use _Full Text Search_ https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx then you won't need to do any of this

Comment: Have you tried to push the result of the profs into temp tables and then union those temp tables .

Comment: @FLICKER - Thanks for the advice it worked well.  From another stored procedure I executed the search stored procedures referenced above, putting the results into temp tables, then I selected and union the results.  This issue has been resolved!